# Hibernate - Seed database without using import.sql

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, seeding

I come from php/laravel. Whenever I want to seed the database i only need to run `php artisan db:seed`. This will run some php scripts that will insert data into the database.

I want to achieve this same feature using spring/hibernate. I know I can add an `import.sql` file to seed the database after schema creation. However, I want to import these fixtures using java and the ORM available so I do not need to maintain an sql.

Is there a way?
If not, there should be some configuration to trigger a script that use the ORM entity manager to persist entities in the database after schema creation.
The main idea is not to maintain a big sql seeder file over schema revisions.

Thanks!

Comment: use a [ContextLoaderListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html) or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Spring data you can use [Repository populators](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.repository-populators).

Otherwise you may register an event that fires after the spring context is loaded :

```
@Component
public class YourListener {

    // Declare your autowired beans here 

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        // Your seeder 
        // + You can use all the registred beans (repositories, services...)
    }
}
```

For more detail check: [Better application events in Spring Framework 4.2](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2)